# Daily Sentiment Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vader

Does anyone have an idea into calculating the average sentiment values for each day?
This is my code get get the sentiment score, but I have tried calculating an average for each of the day, but i havent had any luck

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import pandas as pd
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

eth = pd.read_csv("Ethereum_2020_2021_Time_Adjusted.csv")
eth['Sentiment Values'] = eth['Title'].apply(lambda Title: analyzer.polarity_scores(Title))
eth['Title Sentiment Score']  = eth['Sentiment Values'].apply(lambda score_dict: score_dict['compound'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **groupby** and **agg** to address the issue.

> eth.groupby('Date')['Sentiment Values'].agg('mean')